# Multi file upload with metadata with relation to every file in a single http request

Tags: angularjs, spring, http, file-upload, groovy

I'm working on a service (front-end and back-end) that will allow to upload multiple files and metadata to every file, so I will be able to generate a specific path to save the files. (metadata will give me all the information about the path). Also, the request will contain information that needs to be saved to DB (this part is working fine), so its all transactional. So the only thing that I can't figure out is how to send and accept metadata to every file.

Front-end: Angularjs

Back-end: Groovy/Java, Spring 3.0

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view/single/multi-file", method = POST, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
def createNewAdjustment(@RequestParam("files") List<List<MultipartFile>> files,
                        @RequestParam("data") List<DataRequest> data){}
```

So in the code above:

```
- the list of lists: are the files that needs to be processed and saved.
- the data: is the list of objects that needs to be processed,saved and interconnect them with files.
```

The request payload looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryPve8x58T1pAIsQOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"rollNumber":"1111111111111","compId":213131,"adjId":"260b018c-5921-4c1c-aa99-ba8587ee4777"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryPve8x58T1pAIsQOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="some.json.gz"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip


------WebKitFormBoundaryPve8x58T1pAIsQOS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="someother.csv.gz"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip


------WebKitFormBoundaryPve8x58T1pAIsQOS--
```

You can see **'name: "file"'** repeats 2 times and I'm not sure how to set it manually or/and attach more into to the request. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this :)

So from the front-end (AngularJS):

```
$upload.upload({
    url : 'upload',
    headers: {'myHeaderKey': 'myHeaderVal'},
    data : {
        myModel : $scope.myModel,
        array: [1,2,3]
    },
    formDataAppender: function(fd, key, val) {
        if (angular.isArray(val)) {
            angular.forEach(val, function(v) {
                fd.append(key, v);
            });
        } else {
            fd.append(key, val);
        }
    },
    file : $file,
    fileFormDataName: 'myFile'
})
```

formDataAppender will add a new part to the request and you can customize the name for every single file you are sending. (exactly what is needed).

From the back-end (Spring Groovy):

```
@Autowired DbRepository dbRepo
@RequestMapping(value = "/docs/upload", method = POST)
ResponseEntity<String> docsUpload(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("data") String data) throws IOException {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request
    List<List<MultipartFile>> files = new ArrayList<List<MultipartFile>>()
    multipartRequest.getFileNames().each {
        files.add(multipartRequest.getFiles(it))
    }
    PoJoObject pojoObject = mapper.readValue(data, PoJoObject)

    files.each { def it ->
      it.each { def itf ->
        log.debug(itf.originalFilename) // the name of the actual file
        log.debug(itf.name) // the custimized field from formDataAdapter

        // in here you can process every field in 'PoJoObject' and make
        // relation to the the file
      }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This solution works for me and solves the issue I had :) Now I can save data and corresponding files transactionally in a single request.